# I have created this Content Censor Code for Wordpress (needed for Ezoic)

Tags: wordpress

I have created this Content Censor Code for Wordpress, this code is very helpful for those bloggers who monitized their websites using ezoic ads. Bcz ezoic has an Objectionable Content option.

This code worked for me, that's why i am sharing this code with you, if someone want to modify this code or want to increase features can do it:

```
///Content Censor code


function censor_content($content) {
    // Array of words to censor
    $censored_words = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3');

    // Loop through each word to censor
    foreach ($censored_words as $word) {
        // Create a regular expression pattern to match the word
        $pattern = '/\b' . $word . '\b/i';

        // Replace the word with censored version
        $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
            $word = $matches[0];
            $censored_word = substr($word, 0, 2) . str_repeat('*', strlen($word) - 3) . substr($word, -1);
            return $censored_word;
        }, $content);
    }

    // Return the censored content
    return $content;
}

// Add the censor_content function to the WordPress content filter
add_filter('the_content', 'censor_content');
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a suitable forum for publishing code. Use a gist or a blog post or something. Or, try posting it in a question (how do I ....) and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your functions.php or custome plugin file

```
///Content Censor code


function censor_content($content) {
    // Array of words to censor
    $censored_words = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3');

    // Loop through each word to censor
    foreach ($censored_words as $word) {
        // Create a regular expression pattern to match the word
        $pattern = '/\b' . $word . '\b/i';

        // Replace the word with censored version
        $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
            $word = $matches[0];
            $censored_word = substr($word, 0, 2) . str_repeat('*', strlen($word) - 3) . substr($word, -1);
            return $censored_word;
        }, $content);
    }

    // Return the censored content
    return $content;
}

// Add the censor_content function to the WordPress content filter
add_filter('the_content', 'censor_content');
```